# Splitting strings based on another list with multiple words

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split, nlp

I have a dictionary of self-input locations and a list of possible locations from geonamescache.
For example, a self-input user location could be "san bernadino ca" and the list of all locations contains both "san bernadino" and "ca." I am trying to figure out how to split the string "san bernadino ca" into ["san bernadino", "ca"] based on the second dictionary. This is in Python.

What I have tried:

```
Let user_locations be a list of self-input user locations.
Let locations be a dict of real location names/keys (like "california", "ca", and "san bernadino") 

for user_location in user_locations
  for location in locations.keys():
    if location in user_location:
      print(location, user_location)
```

But, this prints results like "ar san bernardino ca" even though it's clear the user location is not Arkansas, but AR is the code for Arkansas.
My instinct was to split the place names into a list since in just checks characters and not words, but split() separates san and bernadino even though I want them together.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you supply some sample values for your `user_locations` list and your `locations` dict?  It's hard to know how to help you when we can't see the format of your data.  What would be best would be a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would allow someone to reproduce the results you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show seems like a valid idea to me. Since I don't know what your input data structures look like, it's hard to know what you're getting and what you want the behavior to be instead.

One thing...the way you're using `print` will make it hard to know what you're getting.  The two values you are printing will be spliced together with no delimiters.

Since your solution seemed close to something that would work, I grabbed it and put a solution together that it seems gives you what you're looking for.  Here's what I came up with:

```
user_locations = [
    "It's too hot in san bernadino, ca !!!",
    "my name is Joe.  I'm from Portland, Oregon, and I like apples"
]
locations = {"san bernadino": "", "ca": "", "Portland": "", "Oregon": ""}

for user_location in user_locations:
    result = []
    for location in locations.keys():
        if location in user_location:
            # print(f'"{location}" found in "{user_location}"')
            result.append(location)
    print(f"Result: {result}")
```

Result:

```
Result: ['san bernadino', 'ca']
Result: ['Portland', 'Oregon']
```

I went with a dictionary for `locations` so that I didn't have to change your use of `location.keys()`.  If you don't need to associate values with the found words, you could remove the `:""` from each entry in `locations`, in which case you'd have a `set`, and you could remove the `.keys()` when referencing that structure.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your comment. This was super helpful and worked for the most part.
Here's the problem. If a user puts "California" as their location, in the location dict there is also a location called "Cali," so it gets double counted as "California" and "Cali."

Comment: Hey.  Yeah, I immediately recognized that this solution is not going to be very real-world useful.  I don't know your intent for this code, so I just left those thoughts alone.

Comment: Finding whole words is pretty simple using regular expressions.  In fact, I wouldn't even think to use "for x in str" to search through a string.  I use regex for pretty much everything, even if it's overkill.  So just matching only whole words would be a big help.  It would solve the case you cite.  But there are other more insidious ambiguities that will arise.

Comment: If I were to start from scratch on this, I think the first thing I'd do is split the strings on whitespace so that instead of strings, I had lists of words.  Maybe you remove the punctuation while you're at it, depending on if that works for what you're doing or not.  Hmmm....what punctuation shows up in city names?

Comment: Ok cool. I'm trying to count up the amount of users who are in certain locations listed in the location dict.

Comment: If you've got control over the list of locations, and it's pretty stable, maybe just doing the whole word thing would be enough.  Do you know enough of regular expressions to do the matching that way...using the notion of word boundaries?

Comment: I've studied them before but forgot a lot of them.

Comment: Something like `if re.find(f"\\b{location}\\b", user_location`) to give you a starting point.  This would basically replace `if location in user_location`.  One question I have is if this works as is when there's a space in what you're looking for.  It should. ... yeah, no reason for it not to.

Comment: re.findall() works perfectly but it's super super slow compared to the regular if statement.